# How to run a js file?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'm trying to get all links of the articles of one blog  ( https://www.mrmoneymustache.com ) so I can compile them into a pdf, but i'm a complete noob in javascript. Somebody on reddit told me to use this code, which is supposed to do what I want :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const e = new EventEmitter();

e.on('fetchPage', link => {
  fetch(link).then(r => r.text()).then(cheerio.load).then($ => {
    const nextLink = $(".next_post a").attr('href');
    if (nextLink === undefined) return; // end on final page
    const postTitle = $(".headline").text();
    const postContent = $(".post_content").html();
    console.log(postTitle);
    fs.writeFileSync(postTitle + ".html", postContent);
    setTimeout(() => e.emit('fetchPage', nextLink), 5000);
  });
});

e.emit('fetchPage', 'https://whatever/post1');
```

But I dont really get how I am supposed to run this program.. Help please ?

Comment: That looks like a node.js script. So use node.js.

Comment: Install Node.js, Install packages used in file, then with `node` command run that

Comment: node namefile.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), then run this command in a command shell:

```
node yourfile.js
```

Comment: I think i'm really near to make it work, now I got this error : 
fetch(pageURL).then(r => r.text()).then(cheerio.load).then($ => {
      ^

ReferenceError: pageURL is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install [node](https://nodejs.org/) and then `node-fetch` and `cheerio` using  [npmjs](https://nodejs.org/), the node package manager. 
Then, run with

```
node thenameoftheprogram.js
```

There are many scraping tools, however, that can be used online and where the learning curve is less steep. They could be maybe be a better match for your problem.

Comment: So I'm now trying to use `npm install cheerio` and npm `install node-fetch`, therefore I get in both cases the errors : 

  EDIT : I wasnt in the directory of Cheerio's files, now I get this ...

Comment: That's a different problem, and that is why I said that it was better to use a tool with a less steep learning curve. `npm install cheerio` should work out of the box. Please step back for a minute and consider that maybe that program is not the best way to solve your problem, since it's causing additional ones.

Comment: I would like to avoid learning everything from Js just for one script...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying... You might want to use things like this https://darrennewton.com/2011/10/30/mirror-site-and-convert-to-pdf/ instead. It's only a matter of installing a couple of utilities.